# Matplotlib animation code throwing a KeyError 0 error

Tags: matplotlib

I'm still new to Python so bear with me if this is a noob question.

I'm trying to animate a chart of CO2 concentrations over time, aka the Keeling Curve.

My csv file contains two columns:
Term (in years back in time, e.g. 0.001) and
CO2 concentration (in parts per million, e.g. 413.53).

My code (the core elements of which were shamelessly borrowed) throws a KeyError 0 error when it gets to the Funcanimation call to Animate().

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated as my Google searches for solutions have drawn a blank so far.

My code is a follows...

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/home/mark/Documents/Data/ClimateData/antarctica2015co2_v5a_stripped.csv')

print(df.head)

Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=20, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(
        xlim=(8000000, 0),
        ylim=(np.min(df)['CO2'], np.max(df)['CO2']))

line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=1)

# Initialization function: plot the background of each frame
#-----------------------------------------------------------
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# Animation function of dataframes list
#---------------------------------------
def animate(i):
    line.set_data(df[i]['Term'], df[i]['CO2'])
    return line,

# Call the animator, animate every 300 ms
# Set number of frames to the length of your list of dataframes
#--------------------------------------------------------------
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(
        fig,
        animate,
        frames=len(df.index),
        init_func=init,
        interval=300,
        blit=True)

anim.save('/home/mark/Documents/Data/KeelingCurve.mp4', writer=writer)
```

I'm running Python 3.7.1, Anaconda 1.9.12 and Spyder 3.3.6 IDE.

Comment: Maybe you intended to write `np.min(df['CO2'])`?

Comment: To get the i'th element of the 'Term' column, use `df['Term'][i]` not  `df[i]['Term']`. Before trying to create an animation, it would be very useful to first just draw a standalone plot.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Your responses unearthed another couple of problems but I was able to solve them for myself.